# Кириллица в Linux версии FPC IDE

Tags: кодировка, ide, freepascal

Кириллица в Linux-версии Free Pascal IDE отображается крякозябрами, в Windows такого нет. Как исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, выполните в консоли команду `locale` и приложите результат к вопросу. Возможно, на линуксовой машине у вас не настроена локаль.

Comment: Если вы первоначально редактировали документ на Windows, он может быть в кодировке [Windows-1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251), тогда его нужно открыть в нужной кодировке на линуксе и пересохранить в UTF-8. Возможно, это придётся сделать другим редактором.

Answer (score 0):

1. Этот пункт не является решением(2 является), но совет использовать другой текстовый редактор/IDE - например, Geany, или тот же vim и компилировать командой fpc . Или Lazarus. Там тоже можно делать консольные программы, отличный редактор.
2. У FP кодировка не совпадает с шрифтов эмулятора терминала. Можешь просто переключать на 866, и будет свет. Читай что-то по теме "имя_твоей_консоли" + cp866 кодировка. Переключаешь и fp работает нормально.